# succession of addition, calculator

Tags: java, android, calculator

I try to program a calculator in Java;
I have a concern when adding several numbers, I can not display has the result that if I click the button equal, for example if I put 1 + 1, when I click its + should show me the number 2, but if I click on another number such as the number 1 show me the screen "21", so I want to add the number 1 !!

```
addition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (clicOperateur){
            chiffre1 = chiffre1 + Double.valueOf(entree.getText().toString()).doubleValue();

            entree.setText("");

        } else
        {
            chiffre1 = Double.valueOf(entree.getText().toString()).doubleValue();
            entree.setText("");
            clicOperateur = true;

        }

    }
});


egale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    chiffre = Double.valueOf(entree.getText().toString()).doubleValue();
    chiffre = chiffre+ chiffre1 ;
    clicOperateur = false ;
    entree.setText(String.valueOf(chiffre));
}
});
```

Comment: add textwatcher to that editext and clear your editext in beforetextChanged method and before that use a boolean variable to check if + is pressed or not and if yes clear that editext for next calculation